# Using a Subaddress on ShapeShift for receiving

Tags: sub-address, shapeshift

I would like exchange BTC to Monero on ShapeShift and i want to know if i can use a subaddress to receive Monero?

Comment: I only used morphtoken with subaddress yet. they worked.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/895b76/morphtoken_announces_support_for_monero/

Comment: Shapeshift supports Monero Subaddresses, tried it today and it worked.